# Transfer app without developer enrollment

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore, apple-id, app-store-connect, family-sharing

I have two apple ID's. I created a new one for my new company and bought enrollment for it. The old account has three apps that are no longer available on the store, since the enrollment ran out of time on the first account.

I have bought memebership for the new account.
It seems like I can't transfer any applications from the old account to the new account before the old account has enrolled again. The option 'Transfer this app' simply does not show up anymore. The apps are stuck at the status 'Pending Contract'.

What can I do to transfer the apps from the old account from the new one?
Will I have to pay for a membership for the old account too?

Comment: I'd contact Apple for support on that.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Support is your absolute best contact. They might be willing to let you renew your old account and then refund the fee once you get the apps all transferred out or be able to work something else out.

- https://developer.apple.com/support/

They could say, you need to pay $200 - one for each account to make them both active and then do the transfer. After all, if you have the code, you could simply recompile and resubmit the app under a new name if it didn't make you $100 to keep the old name in terms of recognition and continuity of app store ratings, good will, reduced app review time.